# PowerShell - Disable-PnpDevice - Why do i get 'Generic failure' when disabling 'Conexant SmartAudio HD' device

Tags: powershell

There is a device called 'Conexant SmartAudio HD' which is causing our Windows 10 20H2 feature updates to stall at 48%. I can see this in the sccm 'UpdatesDeployment.log' and the 'C:$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log'.

I am writing a Powershell script to disable/remove this device to enable the update to continue; That seems to be a solution worth trying according to the research i've done. However, when i run the script to disable the device on the remote machine i get the following error:

> Generic failure
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Win32_PnPEntity..._2008&SUBSY...):ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity) [Disable-PnpDevice], CimException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice
> + PSComputerName        : RemoteDeviceName

I am running PowerShell as Administrator and the code i am running is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "SomeComputer"-ScriptBlock { Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "Conexant Smart Audio HD" | Disable-PnpDevice }
```

I know the device exists, as Get-PnpDevice returns the FriendlyName. I know it's trying to disable the device, as i get a popup after a short while quoting the instanceid of the device and asking if i want to disable it. After clicking yes it returns the error.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

I have also tried the pnputil.exe /disable-device and /remove-device parameters, but they aren't present on our remote machines due to them being Windows 10 1809, it's only available 2004 onwards.

Comment: For me it wasn't working without administrator, but running as administrator got it to work. I'm saying this in case someone else has a failure which can be fixed by running as admin.

Answer (score -1):

you must run `pnputil.exe` with admin rights